# Empty response body from GET request in Twilio Messaging API

Tags: spring, postman, twilio

I'm building a Java Spring application that makes use of Twilio SMS service and it works fine, except that when testing the API with Postman I only get a `200 OK` status but a completely empty response body with no JSON at all. I'm not sure if this is a config issue with Postman or with my code, but it's pretty much following the documentation:

```
@Service
public class SmsService {
    @Value("${twilio.sid}")
    private String twilioSid;

    @Value("${twilio.key}")
    private String twilioKey;

    @Value("${twilio.phone.from}")
    private String twilioPhoneFrom;

    @Value("${twilio.phone.to}")
    private String twilioPhoneTo;

    public void sendSms() {
        Twilio.init(twilioSid, twilioKey);

        PhoneNumber to = new PhoneNumber(twilioPhoneTo);
        PhoneNumber from = new PhoneNumber(twilioPhoneFrom);
        String msg = "Some message";

        Message message = Message.creator(to, from, msg).create();

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api) they show a clear example of how it's possible to get a complete JSON response back from HTTP requests.

Comment: Is this Java code working? If the issue is with Postman, what are the settings you are using in Postman?

Comment: Yes, it's working exactly like expected, I'm getting SMS's with no problem. The *only* thing is this lack of a response body, at least for successful requests, because I was able to get something back from bad requests so, for now, I'm discarding anything related to Postman settings.

Comment: I'm still confused. Do you get a response body back when running the Java code? In the code you posted in the question, you should print out a message SID when the code runs successfully, that SID is part of the response JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed that tutorial and it doesn't really return any messages. If you did the entire Bootcamp from DevSuperior, in Java code it just puts an output to the console to confirm that the message was generated successfully.

probably in your controller it should look like this:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/notification")
    public void notifySms(@PathVariable Long id) {
    smsService.sendSms(id);
}
```

Your service layer should look something like this:

```
public void sendSms(Long saleId) {

  Sale sale = saleRepository.findById(saleId).get();

  String date = sale.getDate().getMonth() + "/" + 
  sale.getDate().getYear();

  String msg = "The seller " + sale.getSellerName() + " was 
  featured on " + date
  + " with a total of R$" + String.format("%.2f", 
  sale.getAmount());
  
  Twilio.init(twilioSid, twilioKey);

  PhoneNumber to = new PhoneNumber(twilioPhoneTo);
  PhoneNumber from = new PhoneNumber(twilioPhoneFrom);

  Message message = Message.creator(to, from, msg).create();

  System.out.println(message.getSid());
}
```

If your return is void, then you won't have any return in the response body.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32899709)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).